# What particular individuals have experienced Nibbana?

Tags: nirvana, sotapanna

Please answer without reciting suttas. I hear often it said that one will neither confirm nor deny if they have.  If you haven't experienced it why would you not just say you haven't? It seems deceptive to me to not just come out and say "I have not" but instead lead people on being mysterious about it.

Straight direct question--
What particular living individuals have experienced Nibbana? Or are most likely to have?

Comment: [This answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/35353/254) mentions "a small taste of nibbana" which implies that at least a taste (experience) might be within reach of almost anyone. See also "stream-winner" and the doctrine of a gradual enlightenment.

Comment: It is not mysterious, it is quite simple that it would bring no benefit from actually saying "I have experienced nibbana and am an arhant" How can you find this comment to be true, how can the arhant prove it to be true. All one can do is teach you the tools to experience the cessation and become an arhant yourself. Now mentioning you are a stream winner, sotapanna is useful, especially for the sangha as that would mean you no longer need "basic" advice. Anyone at sotapanna level and above can see this in you also. Only an arhant can see another arhant, so there is no benefit from claiming.

Comment: I hope you found an answer in the duplicate question that appeals to you. If not, please say so. In Buddhism, there are some restrictive & outdated rules around speaking about such things. It's not a secret, and should no longer be treated as if it is. You might like Shinzen Young's book, The Science of Enlightenment where he speaks openly about his enlightenment and that it is, in figurative terms, a real thing. Good luck.

Comment: I would be careful with people who claim to be enlightened. You often find they are extremely concerned with worldly concern.